# Anaconda3 libhdf5.so.9: cannot open shared object file [works fine on py2.7 but not on py3.4]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, pytables, hdfstore

I just tried to use `pd.HDFStore` in IPython Notebook with a Python 3 kernel (Anaconda 2&3 on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore('/home/Jian/Downloads/test.h5')
```

but it throws the following error

```
ImportError: HDFStore requires PyTables, "libhdf5.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" problem importing
```

I initially thought it's because `pytables` is somehow missing, but when I check `$source activate py34` and `$conda list`, `pytables 3.2.0` is already installed under anaconda python3 environment.

Also, if I switch to Python 2, for example, `$source activate py27` and start `ipython notebook`, it works properly and no import error is thrown.

I guess that I must miss something for configuring `pytables` under anaconda python 3 env, but I cannot figure it out. Any help is highly appreciated.

### Update:

I just tried on a fresh install of `Anaconda3-2.3.0-Linux-x86_64` from official website and it ends up with the same error. When I try `$locate libhdf5.so.9` in command line, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that we are working on. When it is fixed, `conda update --all` will update the libraries and fix the issue.